# Updating calculated total when a property on the underlying item in a list is changed - wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ViewModel (VM is just the code behind to simplify the example) which contains (among other things) a `Pallet` class. On the pallet there are many boxes. In each box there are some pieces.

I have a Wpf form the lists each box on the pallet with a textbox showing how many items are in the box. Underneath this is a label showing the total count of all items on the pallet.

My question is how to get the label to update when one of the textboxes get changed. I think this will have something to do with property change and collection changed events, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I've come across answers that seem to work for adding or removing items from the collection. The problem is that I'm not ading or removing any items. I am only changing a value on an item in the collection. I know there are a lot of questions about this issue, but I haven't been able to find one that works for me.

Here is an example program:

`MainWindow.xaml`

```
<Window>
    <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Pallet.BoxesOnPallet}" AlternationCount="100" Tag="{Binding .}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <!-- Cast 1 -->
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding NumberOfPiecesinBox}" Margin="10" Padding="3"></TextBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Total}" Padding="3"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

---

`MainWindow.xaml.cs`

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Keops.Mes.Casthouse.Entities.BO
{
    public class Box : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public Box(int num)
        {
            NumberOfPiecesinBox = num;
        }

        public int NumberOfPiecesinBox
        {
            get { return _numberOfPiecesinBox; }
            set
            {
                _numberOfPiecesinBox = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("NumberOfPiecesinBox"); 
            } 
        }
        public int _numberOfPiecesinBox;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

---

`Pallet.cs`

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using Keops.Mes.Casthouse.Entities.BO;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public class Pallet
    {
        public Pallet()
        {
            BoxesOnPallet = new ObservableCollection<Box>
            {
                new Box(3),
                new Box(8),
                new Box(5),
                new Box(1),
                new Box(0)
            };
        }
        public ObservableCollection<Box> BoxesOnPallet { get; set; }

        public int ItemTotal
        {
            get { return BoxesOnPallet.Sum(x => x.NumberOfPiecesinBox); }
            set { }
        }
    }
}
```

---

`Box.cs`

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Keops.Mes.Casthouse.Entities.BO
{
    public class Box : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public Box(int num)
        {
            NumberOfPiecesinBox = num;
        }

        public int NumberOfPiecesinBox
        {
            get { return _numberOfPiecesinBox; }
            set
            {
                _numberOfPiecesinBox = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("NumberOfPiecesinBox"); 
            } 
        }
        public int _numberOfPiecesinBox;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example, to update the total, your `Pallet` class would need to "watch" for items being added and removed from `BoxesOnPallet` by handling its [`CollectionChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375(v=vs.110).aspx).  That handler should then hook / unhook the [`PropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event of the added / removed item.  The handler for *that* event can update the `Total` property on `Pallet`.  It's a bit complicated to get everything working together.

```
public class Pallet : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Pallet()
    {
        BoxesOnPallet = new ObservableCollection<Box>();
        BoxesOnPallet.CollectionChanged += BoxesOnPallet_CollectionChanged;

        BoxesOnPallet.Add(new Box(3));
        BoxesOnPallet.Add(new Box(8));
        BoxesOnPallet.Add(new Box(5));
        BoxesOnPallet.Add(new Box(1));
        BoxesOnPallet.Add(new Box(0));
    }

    private void BoxesOnPallet_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {    
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
       {
            foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
            {
                ((Box)item).PropertyChanged += Box_Changed;
            }
        }
        else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
        {
            foreach (var item in e.OldItems)
            {
                ((Box)item).PropertyChanged -= Box_Changed;
            }
        }
    }

    void Box_Changed(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Box.NumberOfPiecesinBox))
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BoxesOnPallet));
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Box> BoxesOnPallet { get; set; }

    public int ItemTotal
    {
        get { return BoxesOnPallet.Sum(x => x.NumberOfPiecesinBox); }
        set { }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Box : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Box(int num)
    {
        NumberOfPiecesinBox = num;
    }

    public int NumberOfPiecesinBox
    {
        get { return _numberOfPiecesinBox; }
        set
        {
            _numberOfPiecesinBox = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(NumberOfPiecesinBox));
        }
    }
    public int _numberOfPiecesinBox;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not adding or removing items.

Comment: Why is `BoxesOnPallet` an `ObservableCollection` then?  The only reason to use that it to allow the collection to be watched for changes. Anyway, the ultimate goal is to have the changing of a property of any `Box` trigger a `PropertyChanged` event on the `Pallet`.  You can either rig up `CollectionChanged` to the collection before items are added, or add the event manually to each item.

Comment: I've included an updated version of your classes that should cascade the property.

Comment: I originally had it sa a list, but changed it to an observable collection while trying things out.

Comment: If the action is `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove`, items in `e.OldItems` should be unregistered instead of items in `e.NewItems`.

Comment: @AlyEl-Haddad You are 100% correct, nice catch. Code has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `Pallet` class so you create a way of telling the view to re-read the correct value; then, you need to monitor `PropertyChanged` event of every item in the collection so you could tell whether a property has changed, while keeping the monitored items list synced with the items in collection.

`Pallet.cs`:

```
public class Pallet : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Pallet()
    {
        BoxesOnPallet = new ObservableCollection<Box>
        {
            new Box(3),
            new Box(8),
            new Box(5),
            new Box(1),
            new Box(0)
        };
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Box> _boxesOnPallet;
    public ObservableCollection<Box> BoxesOnPallet
    {
        get { return _boxesOnPallet; }
        set
        {
            if (_boxesOnPallet != null)
            {
                foreach (Box box in _boxesOnPallet)
                {
                    if (box != null)
                        box.PropertyChanged -= Box_PropertyChanged;
                }
                _boxesOnPallet.CollectionChanged -= BoxesOnPallet_CollectionChanged;
            }
            _boxesOnPallet = value;
            if (value != null)
            {
                foreach (Box box in value)
                {
                    if (box != null)
                        box.PropertyChanged += Box_PropertyChanged;
                }
                value.CollectionChanged += BoxesOnPallet_CollectionChanged;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BoxesOnPallet));
        }
    }

    private void BoxesOnPallet_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e?.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (Box box in e.OldItems)
            {
                if (box != null)
                    box.PropertyChanged -= Box_PropertyChanged;
            }
        }
        if(e?.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (Box box in e.NewItems)
            {
                if (box != null)
                    box.PropertyChanged += Box_PropertyChanged;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Box_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName.Equals(nameof(Box.NumberOfPiecesinBox)))
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ItemTotal));
    }

    public int ItemTotal
    {
        get { return BoxesOnPallet.Sum(x => x.NumberOfPiecesinBox); }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Also, the binding mentioned in the XAML file seems to be `OneWay` which means value will be fetched from the source to the view and not vice versa; instead, this should be a `TwoWay` binding.
`MainWindow.xaml`:

```
...
<TextBox Text="{Binding NumberOfPiecesinBox, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="10" Padding="3"/>
...
```

Comment: Thanks. You would have got the check but Brad was faster! :D