# Observablecollection property changed not showing up in textblock

Tags: c#, wpf

I imagine that this is going to be flagged as a dduplicate but I am kind of stuck and not sure how to interpret other answers, or really know what I am doing wrong. Essentially my end problem is this:

I have a class that contains a field (a number) that can be changed. This class will be in an observable list that should contain a total of all the numbers from all elements in the observable collection. The total number should automatically change when the field of any member of the list is changed by the user. It is actually very similar to the problem posed here: [Updating calculated total when a property on the underlying item in a list is changed - wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51331010/updating-calculated-total-when-a-property-on-the-underlying-item-in-a-list-is-ch). However, when I followed that solution and created a textbox that was bound to the total, the total was never changed. It seems also that the OnPropertyChanged event for the collection is never called to indicate that a property was changed in the underlying list. I think the problem is related to the fact that total_dose is never actually set but just has a get (from the link I provided). I am not sure how to implement the solutions I see on other posts. Would appreciate some guidance

## CS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51331010/updating-calculated-total-when-a-property-on-the-underlying-item-in-a-list-is-ch
namespace WpfApp2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> sub_list { get; set; }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            structure temp_struct = new structure("Bladder");

            structure_info_list.ItemsSource = temp_struct.fx_list;
            this.DataContext = temp_struct;
        }
    }


    public class structure : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public structure(string name)
        {
            this.name = name;

            fx_list = new ObservableCollection<fraction>();
            fraction fx1 = new fraction(3);
            fraction fx2 = new fraction(4);
            fraction fx3 = new fraction(5);

            fx_list.Add(fx1);
            fx_list.Add(fx2);
            fx_list.Add(fx3);

            MessageBox.Show("Total: " + total_dose);

            fx_list[0].fx_dose = 50;

            MessageBox.Show("Total: " + total_dose);
        }

        private void fractions_changed_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            {
                foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
                {
                    ((fraction)item).PropertyChanged += fx_Changed;
                }
            }
            else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
            {
                foreach (var item in e.OldItems)
                {
                    ((fraction)item).PropertyChanged -= fx_Changed;
                }
            }
        }

        void fx_Changed(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(fraction.fx_dose))
            {
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(fx_list));
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

            MessageBox.Show("A property in the underlying list was changed: " + propertyName);
        }
        /*
        public void calc_total_sum()
        {
            int total_sum_temp = 0;
            
            foreach (fraction fx in fx_list)
            {
                total_sum_temp += fx.fx_dose;
            }
            total_sum = total_sum_temp;
        }
        */
        public string name { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<fraction> fx_list { get; set; }

        //public int total_sum { get; set; }
        public int total_dose
        {
            get { return fx_list.Sum(x => x.fx_dose); }
            set { }
        }



    }

    public class fraction : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _fx_dose;
        public int fx_dose
        {
            get { return _fx_dose; }
            set
            {
                _fx_dose = value;
                this.calc_eq();
                this.OnPropertyChanged("fx_dose");
                //MessageBox.Show("FX DOSE PROP");
            }
        }

        private int _eq;
        public int eq
        {
            get { return _eq; }
            set { _eq = value; }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public fraction(int fx_dose)
        {
            this.fx_dose = fx_dose;
            this.eq = fx_dose*2;
        }
        public void calc_eq()
        {
            this.eq = this.fx_dose * 2;
        }

        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
            //PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

## XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl Name="structure_info_list">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="Fraction "/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=fx_dose, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            
        </ItemsControl>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Total: "/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=total_dose, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

---

Edit: I found the solution by looking at section 3 of this link
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28098/A-WPF-Pie-Chart-with-Data-Binding-Support#three

Comment: Did you forget to subscribe to the CollectionChanged event `fx_list.CollectionChanged += fractions_changed_CollectionChanged`?

Comment: Also note that `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(fx_list))` has no effect when the value of the `fx_list` property does not actually change, i.e. a new collection is assigned.

Comment: @KlausGütter I tried this and it doesn't work. From what I have read, the `CollectionChanged` event does not fire if the property of an object in the `ObservableCollection` is changed (even though the description says it does) which is why in the link in my edit they subscribe to each property of the observable collection.

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple if items.
First, you are setting the datacontext and the itemsource after you populate the list - this causes the notifications to not reach your binding.  it is better to set these up in your XAML file.
Next, your property total_does does not call OnPropertyChanged("total_does").
Also, the datacontext is connected to the observable collection within structure.  total_does is outside of the observable collection so your window will not see total_does or its notifications.

I made adjustmnts to show what I mean:

CS file:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> sub_list { get; set; }

    private structure temp_struct;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        temp_struct = new structure("Bladder");

    }

    public structure Temp_Struct
    {
        get => temp_struct;
        set
        {
            temp_struct = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string memberName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(memberName));
    }
}


public class structure : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<fraction> fxlist = new ObservableCollection<fraction>();

    public structure(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;

        fx_list = new ObservableCollection<fraction>();
        fraction fx1 = new fraction(3);
        fraction fx2 = new fraction(4);
        fraction fx3 = new fraction(5);

        fx_list.Add(fx1);
        fx_list.Add(fx2);
        fx_list.Add(fx3);

        MessageBox.Show("Total: " + total_dose);
        OnPropertyChanged("total_dose");

        fx_list[0].fx_dose = 50;

        MessageBox.Show("Total: " + total_dose);
        OnPropertyChanged("total_dose");
    }

    private void fractions_changed_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
            {
                ((fraction)item).PropertyChanged += fx_Changed;
            }
        }
        else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
        {
            foreach (var item in e.OldItems)
            {
                ((fraction)item).PropertyChanged -= fx_Changed;
            }
        }
    }

    void fx_Changed(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(fraction.fx_dose))
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(fx_list));
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new propertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        MessageBox.Show("A property in the underlying list was changed: " + propertyName);
    }

    /*
    public void calc_total_sum()
    {
        int total_sum_temp = 0;
        
        foreach (fraction fx in fx_list)
        {
            total_sum_temp += fx.fx_dose;
        }
        total_sum = total_sum_temp;
    }
    */
    public string name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<fraction> fx_list
    {
        get => fxlist;
        set
        {
            fxlist = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    //public int total_sum { get; set; }
    public int total_dose
    {
        get { return fx_list.Sum(x => x.fx_dose); }
    }
}

public class fraction : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _fx_dose;

    public int fx_dose
    {
        get { return _fx_dose; }
        set
        {
            _fx_dose = value;
            this.calc_eq();
            this.OnPropertyChanged("fx_dose");
            //MessageBox.Show("FX DOSE PROP");
        }
    }

    private int _eq;

    public int eq
    {
        get { return _eq; }
        set { _eq = value; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public fraction(int fx_dose)
    {
        this.fx_dose = fx_dose;
        this.eq = fx_dose * 2;
    }

    public void calc_eq()
    {
        this.eq = this.fx_dose * 2;
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        //PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

XAML file:

```
<Window
        x:Name="WinMain"
        x:Class="DeluxMeasureStudies.Windows.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DeluxMeasureStudies.Windows"

        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="800"
        Height="450"
        Foreground="White"
        DataContext="{Binding   Temp_Struct,    ElementName=WinMain}"
        Background="{StaticResource Normal.Window.Background}"
>
    <StackPanel
            Orientation="Vertical"
            >
        <ItemsControl Name="structure_info_list" 
                DataContext="{Binding Path=Temp_Struct, ElementName=WinMain}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=fx_list}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate
                        DataType="local:fraction"
                        >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="Fraction "/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=fx_dose, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            
        </ItemsControl>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Total: "/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=total_dose, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: "*setting the datacontext and the itemsource after you populate the list - this causes the notifications to not reach your binding*" - this is plain wrong. Bindings are evaluated at a later time. The order of assignments during construction is irrelevant.

Comment: "*the datacontext is connected to the observable collection within structure. total_does is outside of the observable collection so your window will not see total_does or its notifications*" is wrong as well. The DataContext is set to an instance of `structure`, which obviously has that property.